# How to Sync PC, Laptop and Tablet on same network

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, sync, android

I have files that sometimes need moving between PC (Win10), Laptop (Win 7) and Tablet (Android).

Before I had tablet, I've used Windows Homegroup, but the settings went south every time I've turned off the laptop.

Since I've got tablet, I've been using TorrentSync, but I have three separate folders Tablet-Notebook, Tablet-PC and PC-Notebook, which is not great.

Ideally I'd like one folder where I could share files between devices and some extra options would be nice (like auto-sync or sync only on confirmation).

Answer (score 2):

You can have a router/modem which consist a USB slot and able to configure a network storage.

Asus Modem is able to do it. Plug the pendrive in the slot and configure from admin panel, then you shall be able to access it from your windows explore, even android device which have file explore can also access by IP.

Comment: Not an option for me. My ISP supports only few models of router/model that I need to have. But it sounds like a good solution for someone else. +1

Comment: @Zikato: You can connect ANY router to the one supported by your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

There are some cloud solutions that you may want to consider.
I suggest a Personal Cloud <sup>[[0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_cloud)]</sup> in the variant 1 or 2:

1. *Personal Cloud*: this is an *internal solution* with home cloud on one of the home machines (variant 1), maybe your desktop with an open source client-server program as for example OwnCloud<sup>[[0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_cloud)]</sup>.
   [+] Private and personal. You decide the size of your space.
   [-] You have to install a program and you can backup only when the device is turned on. You have to buy your hardware (but you can use your desktop).
2. (Or 1b) *Personal Cloud via router:*  a usb HDD or Pen drive directly attached to your router (as suggested by Kira too), only if the router allow it.  When not, you can add one NAS<sup>[[NAS](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=1140)]</sup>  on your private network. You can decide for an encrypted storage or not encrypted. Some of those solutions are provided by the HDD seller directly (Asus<sup>[[2](https://home.asuscloud.com/navigate/)]</sup>, Seagate<sup>[[3](http://www.seagate.com/gb/en/products/network-attached-storage/home-network/personal-cloud/)]</sup>...).
   [+] No need to keep turned on a machine (your desktop). All the plus of point one.
   [-] You need to buy a router, or a NAS, or a device that transform your HDD in a NAS.
3. *Cloud provided:* external solution as Dropbox or one of the many others <sup>[[Top10](http://www.zdnet.com/article/the-top-10-personal-cloud-storage-services/)]</sup>, in which the cloud system is located and administrated in another place. You can use encryption locally and backup the encrypted version of your files.
   [+] You have not to be worried about HDD failure and backups, neither to buy them.
   [-] You give your data to somebody else, you use your network connection, you have limited free space or you have to pay for it.

Note: a singular variant of the point #2: you can buy a box for television, maybe a wireless one, that has the possibility to used as NAS service. It means you attach to the usb port a pen drive or an HDD. At present are not always more expensive than the difference between an HDD and a NAS, or a new router, and you can have an internet television box for you (Again there are service at payment and for free. Search on internet for "box television" or for "kodi"...).